# Android OpenGL memory usage profiling?

Tags: android, memory, opengl-es, ddms

I'm struggling with some issues which I believer are memory related with my Android app, yet I can't seem to figure out how to get information on how much memory my app is using.

I have a suspicion that some textures I am loading are not getting cleared by the garbage collector, but I want to be able to test before I start blindly making changes.

I've been struggling with DDMS for hours, and while I can get it to connect, I can't make heads or tails of the output.  The allocations only seems be showing me basic object allocations, whereas what I'm concerned about is what's going on with memory using by things like my openGL textures and audio files.

Any advice on profiling memory usage in openGL apps on Android would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are the symtoms that make you think the textures are not being garbage collected?

Comment: My game transitions from level to level.  During these transitions I typically dump 1 texture and load a new one.

It works for a while, but after 10 or so transitions fps starts to drop.  Another 5 or so I see messages in LogCat:
INFO/ActivityManager(1239): Low Memory: No more background processes.

Then a lot of:
DEBUG/Cursor(1239): fillWindow is not executed because Cursor object is closed.

I can't be sure it's texture related, but it's my best guess and there has to be a way to see how much memory I'm using over time no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uhm have you call gldeletetexture on the textures you want to unload? 
you have to manually delete your texture( like your level background and such) if you don't plan to use it anymore.